# Sorting ArrayList of String[]

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an arraylist of String[]:

> *ArrayList< String [] > mystuff = new ArrayList < String [] > ();*

I want to sort them in largest-array-size ascending order. Example:

> mystuff = {["this", "is", "item",
>   "one"], ["this", "is", "item", "two"],
>   ["item"], ["item", "three"]}

Should become:

> mystuff = {["item"], ["item",
>   "three"], ["this", "is", "item",
>   "one"], ["this", "is", "item", "two"]}

For arrays of equal length, the order doesn't matter.

**Edit:**

> Java compiler version: javac 1.6.0_20
>
> Error that I am facing by using
>   @sepp2k's code:
>   http://pastie.org/private/ienpdtj0ft6czw6nboeva

Comment: I still need to see the code you're trying to compile. It looks like you put the call to sort somewhere where expressions aren't syntactically valid (like outside a method definition for example).

Comment: Looks like you're missing some punctuation somewhere.

Comment: I was putting the code within my class declaration however putting it right after my import cut it down to 3 errors: http://pastie.org/1029778

Comment: @khan0: You need to put it inside a method.

Comment: @khan0: You can't put it after the import or inside the class. It needs to be inside some function.

Comment: @khan0: don't use pasties.  In a few hours / days they may be gone, making your question useless.

Comment: @khan0: May I also suggest that you won't ever properly understand Java if you just randomly copy and paste other people's code fragment.  Read a good text book or Sun's online Java tutorials.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `Collections.sort` with a `Comparator` that compares the length.

```
Collections.sort(mystuff, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    public int compare(String[] x, String[] y) {
        if(x.length < y.length) {
            return -1;
        } else if(x.length == y.length) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
});
```

Edit: Here's a complete class that compiles and runs without error (and shows the correct result):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Bla {                         
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create list
        List<String[]> mystuff = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        mystuff.add(new String[] {"lilu", "lolo"});
        mystuff.add(new String[] {"lala"});
        mystuff.add(new String[] {"lila", "blabla", "pfirsichkuchen"});

        // Sort list
        Collections.sort(mystuff, new Comparator<String[]>() {
            public int compare(String[] x, String[] y) {
                if(x.length < y.length) {
                    return -1;
                } else if(x.length == y.length) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        });

        // Output list
        for(String[] strs : mystuff) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strs));
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yikes, my compiler throws a bunch of errors. Is it because I am importing:

import java.util.*;

Comment: @khan0: It's not because you're importing `java.util.*`. That's fine. Please edit your question to show the whole code that causes the error and the error message. And your java version.

Comment: Ummm ... (potentially) creating two `Integer` instances so that you can use the `compareTo` method seems a bit wasteful.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sepp2k, it works now. @Stephen C, I will take your advice and get started on some reading soon times. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: The whole if/else block can be removed and replaced with return x.length-y.length. The value doesn't matter, just whether it's zero, positive or negative.